# How convert raw data to useful angles?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32

I use Gyro L3GD20 and STM32F4 microcontroller. I get this data from gyro sensor.

0, -1, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -6, -5, -3, -4, -4, -5, -6, -5, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -4, -4, -4, -3, -3, -3, -3, -5, -5, -5,
-4, -4, -4, -5, -5, -6, -6, -5, -5, -6, -6, -8, -9, -10, -10, -11, -12, -14, -16, -17, -16, -14, -12, -11, -10, -8, -7, -8,
-8, -8, -8, -6, -5, -4, -4, -2, -2, -3, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1, -2, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3,
4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 19, 17, 13, 9, 9, 14, 19, 8, 15, 15, 17, 17, 18, 17, 14, 14, 15, 15,
11, 7, 5, 5, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

This relates to the *angular-velocity* along the x-axis.
I would like to extract angle from raw data.
Piece of code

```
while(1)
{
    if(measure)
    {
        ///20 ms///.
        L3GD20_Read(&L3GD20_Data);
        int16_t x = L3GD20_Data.X;
        USART_putint(USART2, _x, 10);
        USART_SendData(USART2, ',');
        measure = 0;
    }
}
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: please format your question, it's too hard to read it, you can use the markdown to make it nice.

Comment: This is very specific to the gyro you're using. You're probably going to have to consult the datasheet which will tell you range, step size, etc, and then you must apply some basic conversion.

Comment: Given only the velocity of the x axis, how can you calculate any angle? Angle towards what?

Comment: I want calculate angle of rotation along the x-axis only.

Comment: @Lundin : X, Y and Z are the terms used in the data sheet for the three axes (yaw/pitch/roll). It is a measure or *angular velocity* not *linear velocity*.

Comment: Your sample values look rather low given that this is a 16 bit part, a value of 19 corresponds to 0.045 degrees per second at the part's most sensitive range of 250 deg/s.  Are you sure you have configured the part and are reading the data correctly?  The data is read from two 8 bit registers - have you read both high and low bytes?

Answer (score 3):

A MEMS gyroscope is an *angular velocity* sensor where the output proportional to degrees-per-second.  To obtain *relatve orientation* from angular-velocity, you must integrate over time, which will get you the change in angle over that time.  Essentially the change in angle is proportional to the sum of all angular-velocity samples.

The L3GD20 is a three-axis sensor so can provide output for yaw, pitch and roll.  It has an I2C/SPI digital interface and performs the sampling and timing for you, and places the data in a FIFO, so you probably should not second guess that timing by only reading at 20ms intervals; rather you should read all available data in response to the data-ready interrupt.  (The mimimum output data rate of the part is 95 samples per second, so you are loosing data when reading at 50sps).  How you do that depends on the API you are using.  It has programmable sensitivity of 250, 500 or 2000 degrees per second; you should use the lowest value practical to get the highest resolution.

```
#define GYRO_FS_DPS 250
#define GYRO_ABS_SAMPLE_MAX 0x7fff 

long x_integrator = 0 ;

while(1)
{
    while( /* L3GD20 data available */ )
    {
        L3GD20_Read( &L3GD20_Data ) ;

        x_integrator += L3GD20_Data.X ;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then relative orientation in degrees is determined at any time by:

```
orientation = ((x_integrator * GYRO_FS_DPS) / GYRO_ABS_SAMPLE_MAX) % 360 ;
```

Ultimately you need to clearly understand the part's [datsheet](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00036465.pdf), it is a very flexible and configurable part and exactly how you process its data will depend a great deal on how you have set it up.

Comment: Nice write-up +1.  Minor: `#define` --> `int` and should not `/ SHRT_MAX` be `/ 65536`?

Comment: @chux :  The data sheet specifies the output as 16 bit two's complement, so the absolute full-scale range is 32767.  In C++ I'd use `numeric_limits<int16_t>.max()` which would be safer; `0x7fff` is probably better here - fixed.